# ion-grid not displaying correctly in ionic/angular project

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to display two columns within a row in my ionic/angular project. And even though I'm using `ion-grid` with an `ion-row` and two `ion-col`s, the content of the second column is being bumped down the page, stacking below the first column - which makes no sense to me. Here is my HTML:

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row style="border: none;" *ngFor="let word of words; let i = index">
      <ion-col style="border: none;">{{ word | acrossWord }}</ion-col>
      <ion-col style="border: none;">{{ word | downWord }}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

So in case the width of both columns together exceeds container width by default ion-raw being a flex container will allow elements inside of it to wrap.

To prevent this behavior you can force "nowrap" using this css class:

```
<ion-row class="ion-nowrap"></ion-row>
```

Under the hood it will do:

```
flex-wrap: nowrap
```

Comment: But if I don't set the widths, shouldn't "ion-row" by default, ensure all "ion-col" items fit within the row? Also, I don't think it's a wrap issue, because the entire contents of the second column are showing up on the right side (as they should), but they're bumped below those shown on the right - from the 1st column.

Comment: hmm can you share screenshot of what happens? or better copy final html with all bindings resolved?